# c++ implicitly convert function arguments via custom assignment operator

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I'm working on a project with is part C written and partly C++ written.

I got 2 Enums which basically represent the same, however one is wrapped inside a class and the other one is located at a global namespace due to C compatibility.

```
//C Code File
typedef enum
{
  C_Enum_first = 0,
  C_Enum_Second,
} C_Enum_T
```

```
//(obviously) C++ Code file
class CMyClass
  {
  public:
    enum class CPP_Enum
    {
      first= 0,
      second,
    };

    CPP_Enum& operator= ( const C_Enum_T& rhs);
}
```

Now I have a function at a global namespace scope with takes the Cpp Enum as an argument

`bool FooFunc(const CMyClass::CPP_Enum value);`

However due to compatibility issues with C code there are some places where this function will be called with a C Enum value

`bool res = FooFunc(C_Enum_Second);`

This gives me a no known conversion error.
Yes I know i can overload, but for demonstration purposes i only showed 1 enum argument. In reality there are 3 enums with will increase my needed overloads.
Why is my assignment operator not called? Do assignment operator not work implicitly on function arguments?

thx for your help

greets Julian :)

Comment: For implicit conversion from one type to your class, you need a non-explicit *constructor*, not assignment operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do assignment operator not work implicitly on function arguments?

Your `operator=` is a member of `CMyClass`. It can be called like this:

```
CMyClass cmc;
C_Enum_t a;
CPP_Enum& x = (cmc = a);
```

But it will not be considered for implicit conversion from `CMyClass` to `CPP_Enum`. Consider to use a free function for the conversion instead. Also it is rather fishy that your `operator=` returns a reference. You didn't include the implementation, but returning a reference does not look right. What should it refer to?

Comment: Thx I was afraid you might say that

My operator returns a reference because Cpp Reference provided this syntax
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment

All of my Copy/Move Assignment operators return a reference as well. Is this wrong?

Comment: @JHeni often operators return a reference to `this` which is completely fine, but in this case it isnt clear what the returned reference refers to, because the object it is called on is not a `CPP_Enum`.